# Unable to start Riak CS?

Tags: riak, riak-cs

I am unable to start Riak CS? In the app.config for Riak, Riak CS. I've replaced the localhost IP address 127.0.0.1 with 0.0.0.0. Riak is running fine. I get a "pong" response. But Riak CS says "Node 'riak-cs@0.0.0.0' not responding to pings."

Comment: What happens when you do riak-cs start? And when you do stanchion ping?

Answer (score 2):

While the HTTP and Protocol Buffer interfaces can bind to all IP addresses by defining 0.0.0.0 as an IP address, the nodes need to have a name that can be resolved as it is used when connecting nodes. `riak-cs@0.0.0.0` will therefore not work.